# match phrase query not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

Reading from elastic documentation:

> the  `match_phrase`  query first analyzes the query string to produce a list of terms. It then searches for all the terms, but keeps only documents that contain  *all*  of the search terms, in the same  *positions*  relative to each other.

I have configured my analyzer to use edge_ngram with keyword tokenizer :

```
{
        "index": {
            "number_of_shards": 1,
            "analysis": {
                "filter": {
                    "autocomplete_filter": {
                        "type": "edge_ngram",
                        "min_gram": 1,
                        "max_gram": 20
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": {
                    "autocomplete": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "keyword",
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase",
                            "autocomplete_filter"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the java class that is used for indexing :

```
@Document(indexName = "myindex", type = "program")
@Getter
@Setter
@Setting(settingPath = "/elasticsearch/settings.json")
public class Program {


    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
    private Long instanceId;

    @Field(analyzer = "autocomplete",searchAnalyzer = "autocomplete",type = FieldType.String )
    private String name;
}
```

if I have the following phrase in document "hello world", the following query will match it :

```
{
  "match" : {
    "name" : {
      "query" : "ho",
      "type" : "phrase"
    }
  }
}
result : "hello world"
```

that's not what I expect because **not all of the search terms** in the document.

my questions :

1- shouldn't I have 2 search terms in the edge_ngram/autocomplete for the query "ho" ?  (the terms should be "h" and "ho" respectively. )

2-  why does "ho" match "hello world" when all of the terms according to the definition of phrase query didn't match ? ("ho" term shouldn't have match)

---

**update**:

just in case that the question is not clear. The match phrase query should analyze the string to list of terms , here it's `ho` . Now we will have 2 terms as this is edge_ngram with `1` min_gram. The 2 terms are `h` and `ho` . according to elasticsearch the document **must** contain ***all*** of the search terms. However `hello world` has `h` only and doesn't have `ho`  so why I did get a match here ?

Comment: (1) You haven't added index mapping, neither you have specified the type for `name` field. (2) You haven't specified any sample doc, so we don't know against what data you are try to match. Clarify these points so that people here can help you better.

Comment: @NishantSaini updated the question

Answer (score 1):

1. If you could provide complete, runnable examples for your problems it would make it much easier to help you. For example something like this:

   ```
   PUT test
   {
     "settings": {
       "number_of_shards": 1,
       "analysis": {
         "filter": {
           "autocomplete_filter": {
             "type": "edge_ngram",
             "min_gram": 1,
             "max_gram": 20
           }
         },
         "analyzer": {
           "autocomplete": {
             "type": "custom",
             "tokenizer": "keyword",
             "filter": [
               "lowercase",
               "autocomplete_filter"
             ]
           }
         }
       }
     },
     "mappings": {
       "_doc": {
         "properties": {
           "name": {
             "type": "text",
             "analyzer": "autocomplete"
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }

   PUT test/_doc/1
   {
     "name": "Hello world"
   }

   GET test/_search
   {
     "query": {
       "match_phrase": {
         "name": "hello foo"
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Judging from your search query, you are using Elasticsearch 2.x or earlier. This is a dead version — you should really upgrade.
3. I'm not sure phrase search on edge grams make much sense in combination. What are you trying to achieve here?
4. Why is it matching? Your search query is running through the same analyzer as your stored field. Since you have defined `min_gram: 1`, your `ho` will be searched as `h` and `ho`. The `h` matches the `h` from `hello`. `match` or `match_phrase` doesn't make a difference here with this analyzer.

Comment: I'm using elastic 2.x right. I'm not trying to achieve something here but I'm trying to understand the match_phrase. the answer for my question is in 4, why does match and match_phrase doesn't make difference ? according to the doc all search terms should contain in the document but "ho" is not there . is not that how match_phrase work ?

Comment: to make it more clear the query analyze the string to list of terms `h` and `ho` , in the match query it will match the `h` from `hello` no problem here. but in match_phrase all search terms should match but `ho` doesn't is that right ?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your questions, tokenizer is the problem, "tokenizer": "keyword", search exact phrase and index like one.

[Structured Text Tokenizers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-tokenizers.html#_structured_text_tokenizers)

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer from elasticsearch forum :

You are using the edge_ngram token filter. Let's see how your analyzer treats your query string `"ho"` . Assuming your index is called `my_index` :

```
GET my_index/_analyze
{
  "text": "ho",
  "analyzer": "autocomplete"
}
```

The response shows you that the output of your analyzer would be two tokens at position 0:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "h",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 2,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "ho",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 2,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

What does Elasticsearch do with a query for two tokens at the same position? It treat's the query as an "OR", even if you use a type `"phrase"` . You can see that from the output of the validate API (which shows you the Lucene query that your query was written into):

```
GET my_index/_validate/query?rewrite=true
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": {
        "query": "ho",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Because both your query and your document have an `h` at position 0, the document is going to be a hit.

Now, how to solve this? Instead of the edge_ngram token filter, you could use the [edge_ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html). This tokenizer increments the position of every token it outputs.

So, if you create your index like this instead:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "analysis": {
      "tokenizer": {
        "autocomplete_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 20
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "autocomplete_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You will see that this query is no longer a hit:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": {
        "query": "ho",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But for example this one is:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": {
        "query": "he",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```